# How to implement apt-get fancy progress bar in my own program under linux terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

[image: apt fancy progress bar]

How can I implement a progress bar like apt, so that it won't interfere with other output?

Any language would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `tqdm` library.

Example from their github page:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    print(i)
```

You can look at their source code and see how it's implemented. I think they use the best practices in this subject:
[tqdm on github](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)

Note that there also exists other libraries in python and other languages so you can check them out as well.

Comment: Thanks, tqdm is a great library. The reason that I want an apt-style progress bar is that a normal progress bar usually interferes with other output. The `tqdm` library still uses carriage return (\r) to implement the progress bar, which means it also has the problem.

Comment: @whenov, A more radical way is to look at how progress bar in apt is implemented. It's open source as well ))).

Comment: I think the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library might be able to do what you want to achieve here.